# Why is IE7 showing scrollbars on rollover?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Can anyone tell me why IE7 shows vertical and horizontal scrollbars on hover of the My Account tab/link at the top right of http://www.myhome.ie?

I've gone through the css and can't see any issue. It's also only happing in IE7.

Cheers,
Denis

Comment: It's not doing it in IE6 or IE8/IE7compat mode, did you manage to fix it?  Try clearing the cache and check it again.

Comment: When I use IE8 with Browser Mode: IE7 & Document Mode: IE7 Standard I see it and I've tried it in IETester and a real IE7/Vista machine which all show it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out to be the negative margins acting up. I removed them and used positioning instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would look for is where your popup menu is going.  If there are scrollbars, then there are objects outside of the visible viewport.  The "My Account" link is the only one without the visible menu.

Comment: My Account isn't given any data for the popup and rechecking the styles I can't see anything.

Comment: What do you mean, it "isn't given any data for the popup"?  -  Check to see what code is running on mouseover.  It may be creating the popup anyway - or it may be simply moving it out of the way (in an attempt to hide it).

Comment: If you run the page without js you don't see any dropdown menus bar the one on the currently selected menu/tab. JS adds the data for the others for SEO reasons. My Account doesn't have these html nodes at all and I can see anything that would add them or move anything else to make an element be outside of the viewport.

Comment: If it were me, I would remove code until this doesn't occur. Then put code back one line at a time until it occurs again. There, the line you found is the culprit.

Comment: Gabriel, I tried to look into his CSS but it was just dirty, so I gave up immediately. I'm sure I can find the issue but my goodness clean up that CSS!

Answer (score 0):

Did you already fix this? I can't see the scrollbars with IE8 in IE7 compatibility view, or with IETester in IE7 mode. If you're still seeing scrollbars, though, you've got an element somewhere with overflow:hidden or overflow:auto - that's where I'd start looking.